# What rating system does the Play Magnus app use?

Tags: rating

I played a total of 261 games against the Play Magnus app at different ages. My overall score is 144 wins, 99 losses and 16 draws. My last game was against the 10-year-old Magnus. Prior to the start of the game I was rated 1248. I won the game and my rating increased by an astonishing 133 points, so I was wondering what is the rating system used.

Most weird is that I sometimes draw against a far higher rated Magnus and lose rating points (I once drew 26-year-old Magnus and lost 18 rating points when I was rated only 1486). Is there any explanation for that, or is it a bug in the app?

Comment: This is a customer support question.

Answer (score 4):

This is a list of Magnus Carlsen’s ratings at each of his birthdays.

- 9 years old: 900
  Norwegian rating.
- 10 years old: 1645
  Still Norwegian rating.
- 11 years old: 2127
  FIDE rating now.
- 12 years old: 2250
  Magnus became an FM at age 11.
- 13 years old: 2450
  Magnus became an IM at age 12.
- 14 years old: 2581
  Magnus became a GM at age 13, the youngest in the world and the second youngest ever at the time.
- 15 years old: 2570
  Magnus went through his only real slump that year.
- 16 years old: 2698
  Magnus played in his first super tournaments right around this time.
- 17 years old: 2714
  Magnus reached 2700 at 16 as the youngest ever, a record that has since been beaten by Wei Yi.
- 18 years old: 2786
  Magnus was now number four in the world.
- 19 years old: 2801
  Magnus reached 2800 at 18 as the youngest ever. The record still stands.
- 20 years old: 2802
  Magnus became the highest rated player in the world at 19, as the youngest ever.
- 21 years old: 2826
  Magnus solidified his top spot on the world rankings this year, and has held it since.
- 22 years old: 2848
  Magnus was really closing in on Kasparov’s rating record now, and surpassed it shortly after his 22nd birthday.
- 23 years old: 2870
  At this point there was a whopping 70 point difference between Magnus and the second rated player, Aronian.
- 24 years old: 2863
  Magnus peaked at 2882 (unofficially 2889) that year, the highest rating ever.
- 25 years old: 2850
  A minor dip in form.
- 26 years old: 2853
  Still number one by a good margin.

About the app - of course there may be flaws, concerning its system there is no information. Although I don't see any reason why they would deviate from the ELO system (which is used in official FIDE games), whose formulas aren't secret and can be found even on Wikipedia.